# Sorting a string with Capital small and numbers

Tags: java, string, sorting

Sort a string with small capital and numbers in Java
aAbcB1C23 .
Answer ABCabc123.

I tried sorting the array both ascending as well as decending but did not work as in both the ways ABC is coming in the middle. Any ideas ?

I'd like to solve with O(1) auxillary space and may be O(n log n) time ..

```
public class SortTheGivenStringAlphabetically {
    public static void performAction() {
        String input = "aAbcB1C23";
        char[] inputCharArray = input.toCharArray();
        sort(inputCharArray, 0, (inputCharArray.length) - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < inputCharArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(inputCharArray[i]);
        }

    }

    public static void sort(char[] array, int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            int pi = partition(array, low, high);
            sort(array, low, pi - 1);
            sort(array, pi + 1, high);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(char[] array, int low, int high) {
        int pivot = array[high];
        int i = low - 1;
        for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
            if (array[j] <= pivot) {
                i++;
                char temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        char temp = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = array[high];
        array[high] = temp;
        return i + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        performAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide code that You tried to get any help.

Comment: How about `new String( Arrays.sort(STRING.toCharArray()));` Or do you want to sort it by yourself?

Comment: That will give me 123 in front but that should not be the case , "ABCabc123" is what is needed.
Sorting in ascending - 123ABCabc
Sorting in descending - abcABC123

Comment: Can you sort it 3 times (lower case,  upper case,  numbers)  and then construct a value to return?  Probably not the most efficient way but still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First loop iterate no of times the no of character present in String.And last two loops run for constant time (78 times).So time complexity wise it could be effecient.

```
   public static String SortSstring(String input) {
        int []intArr=new int[78];
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
            intArr[input.charAt(i)-48] ++;
        String OutputString="";
        for(int i=17;i<78;i++){
            OutputString+=String.valueOf(new char[intArr[i]]).replace('\0', (char)(i+48));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            OutputString+=String.valueOf(new char[intArr[i]]).replace('\0', (char)(i+48));
        }
        return OutputString;
    }
    }
```

Comment: This has worked well. Though the char array creation will take some space depending on the no of times a character is repeated. But time complexity has now been greatly reduced. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2):

- Create 3 `ArrayList`s.
- Separate all characters from the input and add them to the specific `ArrayList`.
- Then sort them using `Collections.sort()`.
- Finally combine all the characters in the order you want.

---

```
String input = "aAbcB1C23";
ArrayList<Character> capital = new ArrayList(),
        simple = new ArrayList(),
        numbers = new ArrayList();

for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            capital.add(c);
        } else {
            simple.add(c);
        }
    } else {
        numbers.add(c);
    }
}

Collections.sort(simple);
Collections.sort(capital);
Collections.sort(numbers);

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for (Character c : capital) {
    output.append(c);
}
for (Character c : simple) {
    output.append(c);
}
for (Character c : numbers) {
    output.append(c);
}

System.out.println(output.toString());
```

---

Output:

```
ABCabc123
```

Comment: It's really not necessary 3 lists due to letters can be sorted together (uppercase are set before lowercase using `Collections.sort`).

Comment: This actually has too many overheads as I am saving each character as an Object in an ArrayList which I feel takes much larger space than doing the same on the array . . Thanks anyway . .

Comment: @H.Aadhithya No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The meanness is that the natural order is `'1' (49) < 'A' (65) < 'a' (97)`.

```
    String input = "aAbcB1C23"; // Sorted: ABCabc123
    char[] array = input.toCharArray();
    sort(array, 0, (array.length) - 1);
```

So either you could reorder the wrongly sorted result:

```
output = output.replaceFirst("^([0-9]*)([A-z]*)$", "$2$1");
```

or map every concerned char to a correct value: easiest with a function:

```
int value(char ch) {
    if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') {
        return 100 + (ch - 'A');
    } else if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') {
        return 200 + (ch - 'a');
    } else if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') {
        return 300 + (ch - '0');
    } else {
        return 400 + (int) ch;
    }
}
```

Now compare `value(array[i])`.

Comment: Yeah This worked , Thanks !! Less complex though.. Thanks. .

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use integer value of a character when doing comparison. To make numbers appear at the end we can add some fixed value to it (e.g. 100).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "aAbcB1C23";
    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
    Character[] charObjectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(charArray);

    Arrays.sort(charObjectArray, new Comparator<Character>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
            Integer i1 = convert(Integer.valueOf(o1));
            Integer i2 = convert(Integer.valueOf(o2));
            return i1.compareTo(i2);
        }

        private Integer convert(Integer original) {
            if (original < 58) {
                return  original + 100;
            }
            return original;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(new String(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(charObjectArray)));
}
```

Comment: Yeah , Thanks ! But I am not supposed to use Java API for this problem ! But a pretty good solution . Worked well. .